# common lisp defclass make-instance usage in custom macro

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sbcl, clos

I have define a macro that create a new class and then defines a constant that creates an instance of the newly defined class:

```
(defmacro my-class (name inst)
  `(progn
     (defclass ,name nil nil)
     (defconstant ,inst (make-instance ',name)))))
```

This seems to work in the REPL

```
(my-class x1025 y1025)
```

But when compiling it in a file doesn't work:

```
There is no class named COMMON-LISP-USER::X1025.
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]

Restarts:
  0: [ABORT] Abort compilation.
  1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
  2: [REMOVE-FD-HANDLER] Remove #<SB-IMPL::HANDLER INPUT on descriptor 8: #<CLOSURE (LABELS SWANK-BACKEND::RUN :IN SWANK-BACKEND:ADD-FD-HANDLER) {13228535}>>
  3: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-PCL::FIND-CLASS-FROM-CELL X1025 NIL T)
  1: ((:METHOD MAKE-INSTANCE (SYMBOL)) X1025) [fast-method]
  2: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (MAKE-INSTANCE (QUOTE X1025)) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
```

Comment: Rainer answered very well, as usually.  However, I want to warn you: "Therefore, users must ensure that the initial-value can be evaluated at compile time (regardless of whether or not references to name appear in the file) and that it always evaluates to the same value." (CLHS, defconstant).  However, each `make-instance` invocation evaluate to non-same value...  So you shouldn't use make-instance in a defconstant.  Use defvar, and don't modify it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class may not be known during compile time in such a way that Lisp can create instances. The standard says that the class should be known during compilation - but not that instances can be created, before the `DEFCLASS` form is actually executed.

`DEFCONSTANT` may evaluate the `MAKE-INSTANCE` form during compile time. As you see in the backtrace, SBCL actually tries to call `MAKE-INSTANCE`.

You would need to make the class fully available during compile time. See `EVAL-WHEN` or put the class declaration in another file, which you need to load before.